# Using array_combine() to keep Duplicate entries (instead of removing them)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$a = [1412, 2634, 1412, 42313];

$b = [16.15, 51.22, 16.15, 120.52];
```

Notice the intentional duplicates on `[0]` and `[2]`.

How can I keep the duplicates when combining these arrays, to output something like this:

```
array(4) {
  [1412]=> float(16.15)
  [2634]=> float(51.22)
  [1412]=> float(16.15)
  [42313]=> float(120.52)
}
```

instead of:

```
array(3) {
  [1412]=> float(16.15)
  [2634]=> float(51.22)
  [42313]=> float(120.52)
}
```

I tried using `array_combine()` and it removed duplicates for me.

Comment: Not possible, arrays can't have duplicate indexes.

Comment: array_combine turns the values of one array into the keys for the resulting array. You can't have duplicate keys that point to different things, even if they are the same value. It would be redundant to do so, anyway, because arr[key] and arr[key] would both point to the same value anyway. The only problem is the array length changes by getting rid of redundancies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, array indexes have to be unique.

The closest you can get is a 2-dimensional array.

```
array_map(function($x, $y) { return [$x, $y]; }, $a, $b);
```

This will return

```
[
    [1412, 16.15],
    [2634, 51.22],
    [1412, 16.15],
    [42313, 120.52]
]
```

There's actually a shortcut for this. If you use `null` as the function argument to `array_map()`, it will simply return an element-wise grouping of the input arrays (like the Python `zip()` function).

```
array_map(null, $a, $b);
```

Comment: Or the shortcut: `array_map(null, $a, $b)`